# My phonegap app not getting installed 'iPad Air' device

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm unable to install my .ipa file (archived and exported from XCode) in my iPad Air (iOS 7.1 is installed). I've an  another iPad(iPad2 with same iOS 7.1 installed) where the same .ipa file is getting installed successfully.

When I try to install it in iPad Air, it certainly starts the installation and finishes but after I tap on it to open it again loops to 'Installing'

Please help me out as I'm caught stranded at the time of releasing the app to the AppStore

Comment: I Think U have to register ipad air Device token in ur device id in Developer apple site.........

Comment: I have already registered my device with apple developer site using my device UDID ... Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast this worked for me!!!

Went back into the iTunes developer portal and:

1) Made sure the UDID of my device is listed on the account
2) Deleted the .mobileprovision file I've been using in my computer
3) Re-generated the .mobileprovision file
4) Re-built the application using the new .mobileprovision file

Please take care of step-2 as that is very important. It is very easy to miss adding the device to the .mobileprovision file due to the iTunes UI. I made this mistake and it drove me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

You should add the device to the apple developper account, then add the device to the used provisioning and download the new provisioning profile. That should work

Comment: Thanks iMarouene. It was an issue with provisioning profile. I've answered to my question below with detailed information as I've resolved it using a workaround.